# Null pointer exception - iterating over FastMap values

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I need to iterate on FastMap.values.
My problem is that basic loop fails over NullPointerException

basic loop

```
Collection<Order> orders = myObject.getOpenOrders();
    for (Order order : orders) {
}
```

problem is that another thread in my system edits the fastmap
It is adding and removing elements to it and I get the NullPointerException.
Rarely, but It should be solved.

So i added Null check

```
Collection<Order> orders = myObject.getOpenOrders();
   for (Order order : orders) {
        if (order != null ) 
   }
```

and still I get the NullPointerExcetion
So I tried iterate it as follows

```
    FastMap<String, Order> openOrders = myObject.getOpenOrdersMap();
    for (FastMap.Entry<String, Order> e = openOrders.head(), end = openOrders.tail(); (e = e.getNext()) != end && e != null;) {
        Order order = e.getValue();
    }
```

But then the loop stops when it gets to null instead of throwing NullPointerExcetion.
And this is also a problem, since I need to iterate all of the elements.

I assume that the problem is that the for iteration uses values() and it is actually a pointer to the list. 
I tried to copy the list but then I also get NullPointerExcetion in the copy process. 
any sugggestions

BTW: I know that changing the whole design is the best solution and using locks in every insert and read. but is there some smaller change I can make in order to solve my problem?
Any idea?

Comment: Javolution `FastMap`? IIRC, Javolution made all sorts of wild claims but the implementation was plain wrong. If you really need concurrent collections, I suggest `java.util.concurrent`. / The `NullPointerException` should contain details of where it was triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not JDK classes? (Javolution?)
From what doc says :

> If the map is marked **shared** then all operations are thread-safe
>   including iterations over the map's collections

So you may encounter some concurrency problem ?
Try that :

`FastMap<String, Order> openOrders = myObject.getOpenOrdersMap().shared()`

Comment: I wouldn't believe the documentation for Javolution.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline You're right, It turns itself effectively into a Hashtable if its 'shared', not very fast if you ask me (because of excessive synchronization).  And even then there is no happens-before relationship between put's and get's of a shared map, ie it's not really thread-safe.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue If you really want a 'fast' thread-safe map (ie shared)  Use a ConcurrentHashMap it will perform much better and actually be thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a multi threaded environment you MUST absolutely use some synchronization, especially when working with iterators.

You cannot iterate a collection while another thread is editing it, this will invalidate iterators and break everything.

So swallow the pill and use some synchronization, this situation requires it.